# When do I need to use cron?

Tags: php, cron

Lets say there is a thread ( on forums ) which will be active for 3 days only. Now, after 3 days, I want this thread automatically closed.

Can I use reference to time when this thread is created in database, and than make **if** statement if current date + days is bigger than date created, I will print out `"<h2>Thread Closed for posting</h2>"`

And when I consider some other tasks, I suppose I can use reference to time and have certain event executed on this.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cron (ran every minute) to set a status field on the thread table to closed such as.

```
UPDATE threads
SET status='closed'
WHERE lastPost+INTERVAL 3 DAY<NOW()
```

Then in PHP something such as

```
if($thread['status'] == 'closed')
{
   // Put your HTML here.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid SQL to me. Was there a typo?

Comment: I think you mean this syntax: `where DATE_ADD(lastPost, INTERVAL 3 DAY)<now()` in your answer.

Comment: it's valid for mysql; it's the short hand for DATE_ADD (or subtract)

Comment: As Dagon said, it's a short hand way of doing it, and personally I think it looks a little cleaner then DATE_ADD.

Answer (score 2):

A 'cron' is a task that runs at a specific interval or time. This means that it should be used for tasks that must be done without user interaction. For example, a backup, automated emails or pulling data from a remote service.

What you want is better suited to a condition on checking whether a thread is closed. Rather than just having a flag, you also check the age. This means you can change your old-thread logic without needing to edit the database.

Comment: +1 for the same reason. Crons can break, stop working, get forgotton when you move/upgrade sites etc. If you need it then great, but if you can avoid, you probably should - and you can probably avoid if the 3 day rule is programmed in as apposed to updating the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a PHP script that gets executed by cron (read up on how to execute PHP in the command line) that SELECTs all the posts in a certain date and then sets them to closed. If you ran that, say, twice a day, then you could do a good job in getting all those posts closed.

[Good reference on using cron to run PHP](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)